How to setup Cereba dataset manually for pytorch?
I have this snippet from here:
    dataset = CelebA(
        root=dataroot,
        split="all",
        download=False,
        transform=transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize(image_size),
            transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
        ]),
    )

It fails with download=True due to too many downloads.

   Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently. Please
   try accessing the file again later. If the file you are trying to
   access is particularly large or is shared with many people, it may
   take up to 24 hours to be able to view or download the file. If you
   still can't access a file after 24 hours, contact your domain
   administrator.

You may still be able to access the file from the browser:
   https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlRnM


I downloaded the file via the browser and unpacked it in dataroot, the images are now in $dataroot/celeba/img_align_celeba/*.jpg.
When I run the snippet with download=False I get:

RuntimeError: Dataset not found or corrupted. You can use download=True to download it

What is the correct location of the images relative to dataroot?
